# Trying to repurpose a MySQL query - anybody have some thoughts?

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a table with some records as below:

```
id  reference_id  message
--  ---------  -------
1   42         Foo
2   42         Bar
3   42         Two
```

Could I use a simple MySQL query to combine all the rows which have the same reference_ID? I want to gather all the rows with the same reference_id values in the same line/row and achieve something like:

```
message1 message2 message3
-------- -------- --------
Foo      Bar      Two
```

The following code from a related stackoverflow post seems to be a possible solution but it applies to combination of two rows only.

```
SELECT a.message AS message1, 
           b.message AS message2
      FROM messages a
INNER JOIN messages b ON a.parent_id=b.parent_id
     WHERE a.id<b.id;
```

I have tried to repurpose the query above to combine three or more rows but I have not been successful so far. 
Does anyone know of a MySQL query that does what I want or alternatively, how to repurpose the code above to do what I am after? Should I ditch MySQL for dealing with this problem?

Comment: This is also known as a 'PIVOT' operation. If there are a dynamic number of columns in the result then a dynamic query will be required; as the output 'shape' of an SQL query must be fixed. In many cases such a pivot operation (which can be viewed as a form of denormalization) can be avoided, especially when joining against other data or when consuming the query via code.

Comment: What do you expect the behavior to be, when not all reference IDs have the same number of messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your above approach like this:

```
SELECT 
  a.message AS message1,
  b.message AS message2,
  c.message AS message3
FROM messages a
  INNER JOIN messages b ON a.reference_id = b.reference_id
  INNER JOIN messages c ON b.reference_id = c.reference_id
WHERE a.id < b.id AND b.id < c.id;
```

Here is the [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ce86/1).

Answer (score 0):

For an dynamic number of results. Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to join the results into a single column in one row per reference_id and then use explode in PHP to split them out.

```
SELECT `reference_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`message` SEPARATOR ',') AS `messages` 
FROM `messages` GROUP BY `reference_id`;
```

Would output

```
reference_id messages
--------     --------
42           Foo,Bar,Two
```

Then in your PHP use explode with the result

```
explode(',' $result['messages']);
```

To get the messages for each row.  If messages contain commas, the use a more distinct separator in the query and explode which can be multiple characters.

Comment: Your suggested solution to use GROUP_CONCAT and then PHP explode appears to be the solution that works.
Using mysql only to achieve the desired result is proving difficult/impossible.